# Error en data provider GxADODataException

Tags: genexus

Cargando un DP me da este error y no logro encontrar una solución.

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

```
07/09/21 15:09:17 - Iniciando carga de Proveedores...Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Thread was being aborted. at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.FetchData(IDataReader& dr)
at GeneXus.Data.NTier.ADO.ForEachCursor.execute()
at GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider.execute(Int32 cursor, Object[] parms, Boolean batch)
at GeneXus.Programs.obteneractualizacionproveedores.executePrivate()
at GeneXus.Programs.obteneractualizacionproveedores.execute(Int32 aP0_ProveedorNumeroUpdate, String& aP1_ProveedoresDataProviderSDTJSON)
at GeneXus.Programs.actualizacion.S151()
at GeneXus.Programs.actualizacion.executePrivate()
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te animas a mostrar el codigo del data provider ? y contar un poco mas de detalle sobre que estas intentando hacer y en que momento da el error? gracias

Comment: Fíjate si tienes bien configuradas las conexiones a las base de datos en el Environment.